# How to apply criteria based styles to a Kendo UI grid?

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui

I am working with Kendo UI; specifically with the grid component. Is anyone aware of a technique that would allow me to style rows based on the data in the row?

For example if the value of one of the columns was negative I would style that row with red text.

I have some ideas on how to do it myself, but I'm hoping someone has already solved this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code was the end solution :

```
var ApplyTestStyles = function () {
    //Get a reference to our data grid
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

    //Get grid data 
    var gridData = grid._data;

    //iterate the data items based on data length
    for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {

        //grab the current grid data item
        var current = gridData[i];

        //the css selector used to find the given data items html table row
        var rowSelector = ">tr:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")";

        //Grab a reference to the corrosponding data row
        var row = grid.tbody.find(rowSelector);

        //apply criteria based styles
        //TODO: refactor this logic into criteria based style providersf 
        if (current.Nav <= 670) {
            row.addClass("Negative");
        }
        else if (current.Nav >= 670) {
            row.addClass("Positive");
        }

    }

};
```

I ended up iterating the data post page load and then applying specific styles.

Answer (score 0):

just read the value with JavaScript out. Then depending on if the value is negative, zero, or positive, or not a number at all you set different styles.